# video auto play without a player (non flash)

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, video

I'm trying to make video playing automatically when page is opened (without a video player skin). I have manage to make it auto play on firefox but it does not work on chrome, also that on iphone and ipad i can still see the default player UI.

http://www.neuproject.writeinks.com/

Does anyone know the best way to make video play automatically without a player ? and it support all browsers and devises ?

i use http://mediaelementjs.com/ for the video playback.

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) which seems to specialise in video and audio implementations without strictly relying on Flash.  You can scroll down to "Browser and Device support" to see a table of browsers/devices it currently supports.

Comment: yea, im already using that, what I need is 1.auto play 2. remove the player ui, i just want to have the video playing. 3. it has to work on all browsers and device.

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of Chrome do not support h.264 video so your issue in that case may be lack of an OGG/WebM fallback. I believe the issue with the controller appearing is because you're relying on the browser default. Set the attribute `controls="false"` on the video tag and the controls should be hidden.

Comment: thanks, do you know how to make the video auto play on Chrome ?

Comment: Well it should be the the `autoplay` attribute. Maybe try simply autoplay rather than autoplay="true". As I said though you do not appear to have any content Chrome knows how to play.